# how to create vuetify icon slid console

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

i am new for vuetify implementing vuetify icon slid console but im confuse.

below console code contained image slide show, using this  code i what to implement example image
i want to show like this
[image]
[image]

```
<template>
  <v-carousel
    cycle
    height="400"
    hide-delimiter-background
    show-arrows-on-hover
  >
    <v-carousel-item
      v-for="(slide, i) in slides"
      :key="i"
    >
      <v-sheet
        :color="colors[i]"
        height="100%"
      >
        <v-row
          class="fill-height"
          align="center"
          justify="center"
        >
          <div class="display-3">{{ slide }} Slide</div>
        </v-row>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        colors: [
          'indigo',
          'warning',
          'pink darken-2',
          'red lighten-1',
          'deep-purple accent-4',
        ],
        slides: [
          'First',
          'Second',
          'Third',
          'Fourth',
          'Fifth',
        ],
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `<v-row/>` inside the `<v-carousel-item/>` then fill it with `<v-col/>`. Each `<v-col/>` represents the image/icon and the caption.

```html
<v-carousel
...
>
  <v-carousel-item v-for="(slide, i) in 7" :key="i">

    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="3" v-for="(images, j) in 16" :key="j">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-center align-center">
          <v-img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" width="50"/> <!-- can also be `<v-icon/>` -->
          <span class="mx-auto text-center caption">Caption</span>
        </div>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>

  </v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```

[image]

Here's a sample [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-murdock-sj13s?file=/src/components/Playground.vue).

Comment: every slide showing same image/icon and the caption how to fix it

Comment: I only did that so you can see the final look. Of course, you need to modify the structure of the data that you will iterate, and define every picture/caption there. I modified my codesandbox demo so you can take a look of a sample structure of the data.

Comment: i am new in vuetify i dont know much knowledge in this i am learning , can you give me i need answer pls

Comment: No worries. The updated codesandbox includes the structure of the data so you can easily follow along. You just need to replace each image src and captions.

Comment: i have one problem i am implementing if i press icon it shoud open router link, please check my question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64085558/vuetify-nuxt-js-how-to-add-routing-link-in-carousels-icon